# Why do different parameterizations give different results for nls?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, nls

## Goal

I'm trying to fit a four-parameter logistic (`A+(B-A)/(1+exp((xmid-input)/scal))`) in R, using nls and SSfpl, to fit two datasets that share the upper, lower, and scale parameters. The input values or the xmid parameter changes depending on a second factor. Since the xmid and input are combined using subtraction (`xmid-input`), it would seem that either parameterization (`(xmid+a*factor)-input` or `(xmid - (input-a*factor))`) "should" be fine and both are equivalent to within a sign difference.

## Method

When I use a fifth parameter (`a`) in the model, whether I put it in xmid or input seems to make a difference. Reproducible (sometimes) code is included here. It creates a real parameter vector, creates a set of data using the SSfpl function, gets an overall fit first ignoring the fifth parameter, uses that to get the start value for the first four parameters, adds a small random value for the fifth parameter, and then fits the five-parameter function. The five-parameter fit happens in four ways: `input+a`, `input-a`, `xmid+a`, `xmid-a`. The four parameterizations are technically identical, (again, plus or minus a sign change).

```
#library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

#utility function for later
add_row_fancy <- function(indata,label,nls_coef) {
  temp_data <- as.data.frame(t(nls_coef))
  temp_data <- cbind(label = label, temp_data)
  return(rbind(indata,temp_data))
}

#Create a real parameter vector
real_para = c(lower=0,upper=1,scale=.2,xmid=0.5,a=.2)
iter_ct = 100

#Create a set of data using the SSfpl function
set.seed(1000)

in_data = data.frame(factor_a = rep(seq(0,1,1/5),times=iter_ct),
                     factor_b = rep(c(rep(0,times=6),rep(1,times=6)),times=iter_ct/2),
                     resp = rep(0,iter_ct*6))

in_data$resp <- as.numeric(runif(iter_ct*6) < SSfpl(in_data$factor_a+real_para['a']*in_data$factor_b,
                                                    real_para['lower'],
                                                    real_para['upper'],
                                                    real_para['xmid'],
                                                    real_para['scale']))
#Visualizer
#ggplot(in_data,aes(x=factor_a,y=resp,color=factor(factor_b)))+stat_summary()+stat_summary(geom='line')

#Gets an overall fit first ignoring the fifth parameter
nls.out.0 <- nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a,
                              lower,
                              upper,
                              xmid,
                              scale),
                 data=in_data)

#Use that to get the start value for the first four parameters
#Add a small random value for the fifth parameter,
start_values = c(coef(nls.out.0),a=rnorm(1)*.5)

#fits the five-parameter function. 
#The five-parameter fit happens in four ways:
#input+a 
nls.out.input1 <- nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a+a*factor_b,
                                   lower,
                                   upper,
                                   xmid,
                                   scale),
                      data=in_data,
                      start = start_values)

#input-a 
nls.out.input2 <- nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a-a*factor_b,
                                   lower,
                                   upper,
                                   xmid,
                                   scale),
                      data=in_data,
                      start = start_values)

#xmid+a
nls.out.xmid1 <- nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a,
                                  lower,
                                  upper,
                                  xmid+a*factor_b,
                                  scale),
                     data=in_data,
                     start = start_values)
#xmid-a
nls.out.xmid2 <- nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a,
                                  lower,
                                  upper,
                                  xmid-a*factor_b,
                                  scale),
                     data=in_data,
                     start = start_values)

#Collect and output the coefficients
out_data = data.frame(label=character(),
                      lower=numeric(),
                      upper=numeric(),
                      xmid=numeric(),
                      scale=numeric(),
                      a=numeric())


out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"as_input_1",coef(nls.out.input1))
out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"as_input_2",coef(nls.out.input2))
out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"input_diffs",coef(nls.out.input2)-coef(nls.out.input1))

out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"as_xmid_1",coef(nls.out.xmid1))
out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"as_xmid_2",coef(nls.out.xmid2))
out_data <- add_row_fancy(out_data,"xmid_diffs",coef(nls.out.xmid2)-coef(nls.out.xmid1))

print(out_data)
```

This gives me the results:

```
#Some percentage of the time -- I don't know why 
> source('nls_test.R')
Error in qr.default(.swts * gr) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
> source('nls_test.R')
Error in nls(resp ~ SSfpl(factor_a - a * factor_b, lower, upper, xmid,  :
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562

#The remainder of the time
> source('nls_test.R')
        label         lower         upper          xmid         scale          a
1  as_input_1  4.150372e-02  1.006742e+00  6.113086e-01  2.006457e-01  0.3144200
2  as_input_2  2.409121e-01  9.385533e-01  4.050761e-01  1.768233e-01  0.3144200
3 input_diffs  1.994084e-01 -6.818919e-02 -2.062325e-01 -2.382239e-02  0.0000000 ##
4   as_xmid_1  2.900963e-02  1.029377e+00  5.795644e-01  2.093002e-01 -0.2339320
5   as_xmid_2  2.900885e-02  1.029356e+00  5.795527e-01  2.092917e-01  0.2339387
6  xmid_diffs -7.863329e-07 -2.099985e-05 -1.177343e-05 -8.483257e-06  0.4678707 ##
```

## Problem

The two critical output lines are annotated with ## at the right. These two lines identify the differences in the coefficients with the different fits. 
Putting the fifth parameter in the input returns the same "a" value regardless of sign, but the other parameters are off by a potentially considerable amount (fit differences in the e-01 order of magnitude).
Putting the fifth parameter in the xmid returns the same "a" value (considering the sign) and the other parameters are off by a small amount (at most e-05). More importantly, the two parameterizations disagree on the value of "a" by a considerable amount (comparing the a values in the lines not annotated, e-01 order of magnitude difference).

What is the source of the instability in these estimates? Is there a "right" way that I should be using? Any recommendations (lme4-nlme tag included because gnls with a binomial family and logit link didn't work well for me, but if that's the right direction....)?

## Update

[image: ggplot of fits] Here are the fit results from a simulation based off the same parameter set as before. As you can see in the column from the far right, the `a` variable gets different fits when it modifies `input` as compared to when it modifies `xmid`. In fact, all of the variables seem more poorly fit when the factor is added to the `input` instead of the `xmid`. What is the source of this instability? Is this a bug in nls or in SSfpl?